# Adding JSON like documents to a new collection Pymongo

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo, querying

so right now I am querying an existing collection within mongoDB for some documents that all have the tag: "_t" : "SkeletonJoints". Once I have these documents, I want to insert it into a NEW collection that is created to hold only documents of these types with the username (e.g. username_kinectdata).

So here is my code:

```
#Import modules needed
import os, pymongo, json
from datetime import datetime

conn = None
db = None
isConnected = False

#try connecting with mongodb server
try:
    conn = pymongo.MongoClient()
    db = conn.emmersiv              #connect to the emmersiv db
    print db.collection_names()     #print the collection of files within emmersiv db
    print "Connected to the MongoDB server"
    isConnected = True
except:
    print "Connection Failed..."

#get all collections in a list and then remove non user data
allUsers = db.collection_names()


'''Filtering Kinect Data By Username'''
for users in allUsers:
    coll = pymongo.collection.Collection(db, users.lower())
    print "Currently looking at", users.lower(), " to filter kinect data"

    #find all skeletal data
    #kinectData = coll.find({"_t": "SkeletonJoints"})

    newColl = users.lower() + "_kinectData" #name of the new collection to be made

    #try to create and insert all kinect data into a new collection
    try:
        for line in coll.find({'_t': 'SkeletonJoints'}):
            print line
            jsonObj = json.loads(line)         #convert to JSON?

            if jsonObj is not None:
                #create collection 
                db.create_collection(newColl)

                #and insert JSON documents
                coll.insert(jsonObj)

                print "Insertion finished for ", newColl

        print "No Insertion for ", newColl

    except pymongo.errors.CollectionInvalid:
        print 'Collection ', newColl, ' already exists'
    except pymongo.errors.OperationFailure:
        print "----> OP insertion failed"
    except pymongo.errors.InvalidName:
        print "----> Invalid insertion Name"
    except:
        print "----> WTF? ", traceback.print_exc()
```

So my problem is when I try insert, there is nothing being inserted. I don't really understand why this doesn't work. I am trying to iterate through the cursor.....

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to convert to JSON: PyMongo reads BSON from MongoDB and converts to Python dicts, and when you pass it a Python dict PyMongo converts it to BSON and sends it to MongoDB. JSON is never involved.

No need to call create_collection, MongoDB creates a collection when you insert into it for the first time.

Your  statement, `for line in coll.find({'_t': 'SkeletonJoints'})`, will retrieve each document from the current collection that has a field "_t" with the value "SkeletonJoints", so I hypothesize that no such documents exist? Have you tried the following in the mongo shell?:

```
> use emmersiv
> db.MY_COLLECTION.find({_t: "SkeletonJoints"})
```

I expect that if you do this query (replacing "MY_COLLECTION" with the name of an actual collection) you'll get no documents in the Mongo shell, either.

Comment: The problem was that my "_t" tag was within a subdocument called "Meta:", so I really couldn't find what I was looking for. There was no need to convert to JSON after all.